# Updating Text view in Widget not working

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I have have an Widget with Configuration activity which update Text view on widget. It works fine, but Same text view needs to be updated on refresh button, which calls same configuration activity. This time configuration activity does not update Text view as it has invalid Widget ID.

I passed Widget ID through

```
Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
refreshIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, refreshIntent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, refreshPendingIntent);
            refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetIds[0]);
```

On receiver side

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Still no reply, I may add here that I am new to android

Comment: Receiver side code is updated above

Comment: This is My first Qustion @ Stackoverflow but astonished that still no advise, no answer. Strange.